# Factory method in an abstract class on flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a mode to create a static method or an factory method in an abstract class on flutter/dart? I need it for my especializations objects to create a jsonDeserialize for example. This method will be called on children to build a particular instance.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from creating `static` methods or `factory` constructors in an abstract base class.  However, they won't do what you want; you can't have virtual dispatch without an object instance, and they aren't considered part of the class interface, so you can't make a generic function that requires specific `static` methods or `factory` constructors.

Comment: I highly recommend serializing/deserializing JSON with an existing code-generation library (e.g. [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value)) instead of doing it manually.